# How to continuously monitor a message queue?

Tags: c++, unix, ipc, message-queue

So in c++, I have a parent process that has forked N child processes. The parent as well as all of its children has access to a message queue, and I want the parent to continually 'monitor' the message queue, and perform `msgrcv()` every time a new message from a child process appears in the message queue. How would I go about doing this? I've read about a `msg_qnum` variable in the message queue data structure, but am unsure how to use this.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual method is just to call `msvrcv` in a loop.  The `msgrcv` call will block until a message is received, at which point the process will continue.  After processing the message, it loops back to the `msgrcv` call which blocks until the next message is received.